# Не могу взять Sprite из DataTable

Tags: c#, unity3d, linq

Логика мне подсказывает, что нет причин по которым картинка не может хранится в таблице, но почему-то достать ее у меня не получается. В поле спрайт после работы скрипта - null. Я не правильно пишу запрос?

Создание таблицы

```
private static void InitSpriteTable()
    {
        SpriteTable.Columns.Clear();
        SpriteTable.Columns.Add("Id");
        SpriteTable.Columns.Add("Sprite");
 
        DataColumn[] PrimaryKeyColumns = new DataColumn[] { SpriteTable.Columns["Id"] };
        SpriteTable.PrimaryKey = PrimaryKeyColumns;
    }
```

Заполнение

```
public static bool LoadInventorySpriteDataTable()
    {
        Sprite[] IS;
 
        IS = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("InventorySprites");
 
        foreach (Sprite s in IS)
        {
            SpriteTable.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s.name), s);
        }
        if (SpriteTable.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
 
        return false;
    }
```

Считывание

```
InventoryItems[i.ToString()].ItemGameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = 
                GlobalStorage.SpriteTable.Select().Where(row => Convert.ToInt32(
                    row["Id"]) == CurrentItem.Id).First()["Sprite"] as Sprite;
```

Comment: Самого строчка `InventoryItems[...` не смущает? машина конечно это прочитает, а вот нормальный человек не станет. 
Логика никогда не подсказывает, она в первую очередь ставит вопрос "Нахера?". Так вот, для чего тебе вообще нужна таблицы? Это просто массив спрайтов, где разницы между `index` и `id` нет, хотя у всех ассетов в `Unity` и так есть свой уникальный `InstanceID`, а на худой конец, по ключу (трудно представить зачем), то это `Dictionary`. Строить какие-то мудренные структуры данных с помощью `System.Data` бессмыслено! Логично? Логично!

Comment: Таблица - побаловаться с не обычным типом данных. И хотелось разобраться почему не работает.
А вот на счет словаря не понял. Почему это "на худой конец"?

Comment: Потому что она A) не сериализуется и соответственно не редактируется в инспекторе B) зачем нужны проставленные в ручную `id`, когда есть индексы массива или уникальные `InstanceID` самих спрайтов.